# Why is Global State so Evil?

Tags: design-patterns, state, globals

Before we start this, let me say I'm well aware of the concepts of Abstraction and Dependency Injection. I don't need my eyes opened here.

Well, most of us say, (too) many times without really understanding, "Don't use global variables", or "Singletons are evil because they are global". But what really **is** so bad about the ominous global state?

Let's say I need a global configuration for my application, for instance system folder paths, or application-wide database credentials.

In that case, I don't see any good solution other than providing these settings in some sort of global space, which will be commonly available to the entire application.

I know it's bad to **abuse** it, but is the global space really **THAT** evil? And if it is, what good alternatives are there?

Comment: you can use a config class that handles access to those settings. i think its good practise to have one and only one place where configuration settings are read from config files and / or databases while other objects fetch them from that config thing. it makes your design more clean and predictable.

Comment: Where's the difference with using a global? Your "one and only one place" sounds very suspiciously like a Singleton.

Comment: you can also have a config object factory or config proxy object, its up to you how this is done. it makes you able to seperate configuration stuff from other parts.

Comment: "for instance system folder paths, or application-wide database credentials ..." storing credentials is a separate topic, but if the settings are read-only, and I mean read-only, then this is fine. In fact, Visual Studio lets you generate settings that are global to the application. if the settings can change, then that is a totally different story .... by the way, dependency injection is an OOP concept. To truly understand why global state is evil, you need to drink some functional koolaid. I recommend pragmatic sources, such as SICP or some Clojure lectures.

Comment: Mutable global state is bad. Very, very bad -- who can you trust to make the mutations? Immutable global state isn't great if it penetrates too deep into a codebase but can be an OK thing in general.

Comment: Also see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392315/problems-with-singleton-pattern

Comment: The only real evil are dogmas.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha There is an excellent google tech talk - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

Comment: Using global state with your fellow programmers is like using the same toothbrush with your friends - you can but you never know when someone will decide to shove it up his bum.

Comment: The devil is evil.  Global state is neither evil or good.  It can very useful or harmful depending on how you use it. Don't listen to others and just learn how to program properly.

Comment: @annoying_squid Please read the first sentence of the question :)

Comment: Even immutable global state can be changed by a programmer when requirements change. I like to be able to see what effects a change will make before I make it, which means reading all of the code that depends on what I'm changing. If I change a local variable, I read the whole function. If I change a private variable, I read the whole class. If I change that global system folder path, I'm out of luck unless I have time to read the entire program.

Comment: @ziGi, What about immutable globals?

Comment: @Pacerier I am not expert but I would say that if it's immutable then you shouldn't have any problems since it is a preset global source of truth of some kind. Although I can't think of that many cases, if you compare it with the toothbrush example, this is like having a locked toothpaste dispenser. The paste is there for anyone to use but noone can replace it with soap, right?

Comment: @ziGi Global constant data is considered a different thing, and I don't recall seeing anyone complaining about that, as opposed to an internet full of people advising against mutable global state. (That's not to say that even constants 'have' to be global, if anyone would otherwise abuse globals for constants that aren't really related but just 'happen' to have the same value... but I doubt that's a very realistic scenario in practice.)

Comment: @PieterB isn't your statement "The only real evil are dogmas." - a dogma itself? hmm... is it evil too?

Comment: @Madara'sGhost Yes, singletons are just globals and therefore, also evil. It's a shame it took the software industry so long to figure that out.

Comment: @PieterB — Bravo!  Absolutely.

Comment: @whyer — No, his statement is not dogma itself. The Paradox of Tolerance explains why it is not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance

Answer (score 346, accepted):

Very briefly, it makes program state unpredictable.

To elaborate, imagine you have a couple of objects that both use the same global variable.  Assuming you're not using a source of randomness anywhere within either module, then the output of a particular method can be predicted (and therefore tested) if the state of the system is known before you execute the method.

However, if a method in one of the objects triggers a side effect which changes the value of the shared global state, then you no longer know what the starting state is when you execute a method in the other object.  You can now no longer predict what output you'll get when you execute the method, and therefore you can't test it.

On an academic level this might not sound all that serious, but being able to unit test code is a major step in the process of proving its correctness (or at least fitness for purpose).

In the real world, this can have some very serious consequences.  Suppose you have one class that populates a global data structure, and a different class that consumes the data in that data structure, changing its state or destroying it in the process.  If the processor class executes a method before the populator class is done, the result is that the processor class will probably have incomplete data to process, and the data structure the populator class was working on could be corrupted or destroyed.  Program behaviour in these circumstances becomes completely unpredictable, and will probably lead to epic lossage.

Further, global state hurts the readability of your code.  If your code has an external dependency that isn't explicitly introduced into the code then whoever gets the job of maintaining your code will have to go looking for it to figure out where it came from.

As for what alternatives exist, well it's impossible to have no global state at all, but in practice it is usually possible to restrict global state to a single object that wraps all the others, and which must never be referenced by relying on the scoping rules of the language you're using.  If a particular object needs a particular state, then it should explicitly ask for it by having it passed as an argument to its constructor or by a setter method.  This is known as Dependency Injection.

It may seem silly to pass in a piece of state that you can already access due to the scoping rules of whatever language you're using, but the advantages are enormous.  Now if someone looks at the code in isolation, it's clear what state it needs and where it's coming from.  It also has huge benefits regarding the flexibility of your code module and therefore the opportunities for reusing it in different contexts.  If the state is passed in and changes to the state are local to the code block, then you can pass in any state you like (if it's the correct data type) and have your code process it.  Code written in this style tends to have the appearance of a collection of loosely associated components that can easily be interchanged.  The code of a module shouldn't care where state comes from, just how to process it.  If you pass state into a code block then that code block can exist in isolation, that isn't the case if you rely on global state.

There are plenty of other reasons why passing state around is vastly superior to relying on global state.  This answer is by no means comprehensive.  You could probably write an entire book on why global state is bad.

Comment: Basically, because _anyone_ can change the state, you can't rely on it.

Comment: @Oded: What would you offer as an alternative?

Comment: @Truth - I was simply trying to expand on what GordonM posted as way of explaining the point of view. I believe global state has its place - used but not abused.

Comment: @Truth The alternative? **Dependency Injection**.

Comment: @Truth I got the impression you were asking why global state was bad.  You might want to update your question to make it clearer you're asking about alternative approaches as well. Am going to make an edit to the answer, but usually dependency injection is favoured these days.

Comment: Note that it only makes state unpredictable if the global variables change.  If they are loaded with constant values then state does not become unpredictable

Comment: Your main argument doesn't really apply to something that is effectively read-only, such as an object representing a configuration.

Comment: @Truth [see also](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/several-classes-need-to-access-the-same-data-where-should-the-data-be-declared/14232#14232)

Comment: @rdlowrey: Why would dependency injection help here?

Comment: @ZweiSteinen By using Dependency Injection you pass values directly into the object via the constructor (preferably over setter methods) negating the need for any global state.

Comment: @briddums in that case you'd use constants! :)  And that is still problematic because the code becomes dependant on the constant.  Even non-mutable global state is best avoided.  Like I said, my answer isn't by any means exhaustive.

Comment: @frankc See my comment to briddums

Comment: None of that explains why *readonly* global variables are bad … which the OP explicitly asked about. It’s an otherwise good answer, I’m just surprised that the OP marked it as “accepted” when he explicitly addressed a different point.

Comment: Your example where one piece of code writes a value and another consumes it is invalid. That is only a problem in multithreading and making the data non-global does not fix it - you need locking to fix it.

Comment: "it makes program states unpredictable" I disagree. To me what you are saying is just a drawback of globals, it depends on how you use them. Of course global variables are not what people should use most, but in some cases, you have to use them, and you have to deal with the drawbacks, and people who program have to know what they are doing, and represent in their mind how the program works to check if all is good. Programmers are expected to design good code, it's not like they will mess up everything because you forbid them to use globals. Don't declare rules on programming style.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The takeaway "negative" for a readonly global is it makes unit-testing **much more difficult**, just like constants. Rigorous, 100% coverage unit-testing *almost* entirely negates readonly globals as viable code inside your functions and methods.

Comment: @GordonM, it's possible to do without global *mutable* state, as in [Joe-E](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/joe-e-ndss10.pdf): "Analysis of who has access to an object and the principle of least privilege are both subverted when capabilities are stored in global variables and thus are potentially readable by any part of the program. Once an object is globally available, it is no longer possible to limit the scope of analysis: access to the object is a privilege that cannot be withheld. Joe-E avoids these problems by verifying that the global scope contains only immutable data."

Comment: `being able to unit test code is a major step in the process of proving its correctness (or at least fitness for purpose)`.  No it isn't.  "It is now two decades since it was pointed out that program testing may convincingly demonstrate the presence of bugs, but can never demonstrate their absence. After quoting this well-publicized remark devoutly, the software engineer returns to the order of the day and continues to refine his testing strategies, just like the alchemist of yore, who continued to refine his chrysocosmic purifications." -- Djikstra, 1988. (That makes it 4.5 decades now...)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ideally, you want most of your program to be *pure* - that is, if I have a function `f` and I call it with argument `arg` twice, I'm guaranteed to get the same result. That makes reasoning about the program considerably easier. Read-only program state is less evil than mutable global state but still leads to impure code, unless it's a compile-time constant.

Comment: "On an academic level this might not sound all that serious": on an academic level the use of global state or even local state is considered to have serious drawbacks, and the advice is to use it only when there is a clear advantage to it. E.g. in the famous SICP book, state and assignment are only introduced around page 218!

Comment: @Doval I completely agree, I was just pointing out that the answer wasn’t addressing this.

Comment: `"the processor class will probably have incomplete data to process"` You can't be serious. A mutex prevents this from ever happening.

Comment: @Navin assuming that one was implemented in the first place. If state is global than all bets are off.

Comment: @GordonM That argument applies to fields, static fields, set() methods, io, and well..., anything mutable.

Comment: "it's impossible to have no global state at all" there are languages where the concept of (mutable) state doesn't even exist.

Comment: I'd postulate that several levels of redundant dependency injection in order to pass some state to a function several levels down also hurts the readability of code.

Comment: @CraigBrett I'd disagree for 2 reasons: 1, explicit dependencies are always better than implicit ones, and 2, if you need to pass one object through a lot of others to get it where it needs to be then there may be questions about your design that you need to look into.

Comment: @GordonM: Sure, but how is a transient dependency that's not even used explicitly declaring anything? Other than "this thing you don't even care about passes through here"? And most real life code isn't necessarily a few flat airy fairy classes.

Comment: For reference, also see https://media.giphy.com/media/9BzeCw4XfMqas/giphy.gif.

Comment: @Oded, And what about if they are **static immutable**?

Comment: @Oded, Re "..you can't rely on it..", and what about multithreaded apps? Just because the obj is supplied as a parameter to the function, it doesn't mean that another thread may not be modifying it anyway. You can't assume it's not gonna change.

Comment: @GordonM I have question regarding last statement in 2nd para - `You can now no longer predict what output you'll get when you execute the method, and therefore you can't test it`. I assume this scenario is possible when tests are running out of order in a test suite but what if I fix the order of execution of my tests. Doesn't that mean that now I can predict the global state as opposed to when various tests are running randomly in a test suite?

Comment: @YugSingh That's the wrong question to ask.  You shouldn't be asking yourself "Can I re-write my test to pass by changing the test?" You should be asking "How can I re-write my code so that it's more likely to pass the test?" Removing the requirement that methods must be called in a particular order is very high on the list of ways to make your code more robust.

Comment: @CraigBrett isn't it a code smell when you need to pass some variable deep inside your code and no outer code needs to know about it? could you give an example where it's a good design?

Comment: Globals that are immutable aren't.........variables.

Comment: I must add that global variables tabu is a huge problem. We have refactored Fortran projects from globals to more modular, just to go back... The truth is the code complexity grew exponentially and we got to break our heads more with scope and allocation errors. We noticed that it was best to move all this complexity up, to a python wrapper and maintain the core model fast and easy to code for the scientists and us, `yes, with globals`.

Comment: "Very briefly, it makes program state unpredictable." - I've used to believe in this too, but I've seem more than enough proof that it really doesn't matter if your state is global or provided by dependency injection or served in a silver platter by some weird AI framework - a programmer _will_ find ways to create unpredictable code, whatever the tools that are given to them.

Comment: I'll even go further - Global state can reduce a lot of the project's complexity when used for the proper things. Nowadays I see this stance as more dogma than anything - akin to banning hammers because people can hit their thumbs with it if they don't take proper care when using the thing. I second @RomuloPBenedetti words.

Comment: Also, mind - having stated passed down by reference gives you no safety rails regarding multhreading, etc - if another piece of code is pointing to the same state object, you will end up having the same downsides that Global State gives you, but with more pointers and wrapped in a fancy package.

Comment: @T.Sar I make an argument that globals have no real impact on predictability in my answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450919/why-blaming-global-state-instead-of-my-user-requirements-makes-program-state)

Answer (score 174):

Mutable global state is evil for many reasons:

- **Bugs from mutable global state** - a lot of tricky bugs are caused by mutability. Bugs that can be caused by mutation from anywhere in the program are even tricker, as it's often hard to track down the exact cause
- **Poor testability** - if you have mutable global state, you will need to configure it for any tests that you write. This makes testing harder (and people being people are therefore less likely to do it!). e.g. in the case of application-wide database credentials, what if one test needs to access a specific test database different from everything else?
- **Inflexibility** - what if one part of the code requires one value in the global state, but another part requires another value (e.g. a temporary value during a transaction)? You suddenly have a nasty bit of refactoring on your hands
- **Function impurity** - "pure" functions (i.e. ones where the result depends only on the input parameters and have no side effects) are much easier to reason about and compose to build larger programs. Functions that read or manipulate mutable global state are inherently impure.
- **Code comprehension** - code behaviour that depends on a lot of mutable global variables is much trickier to understand - you need to understand the range of possible interactions with the global variable before you can reason about the behaviour of the code. In some situations, this problem can become intractable.
- **Concurrency issues** - mutable global state typically requires some form of locking when used in a concurrent situation. This is very hard to get right (is a cause of bugs) and adds considerably more complexity to your code (hard/expensive to maintain).
- **Performance** - multiple threads continually bashing on the same global state causes cache contention and will slow down your system overall.

Alternatives to mutable global state:

- **Function parameters** - often overlooked, but parameterising your functions better is often the best way to avoid global state. It forces you to solve the important conceptual question: what information does this function require to do its job? Sometimes it makes sense to have a data structure called "Context" that can be passed down a chain of functions that wraps up all relevant information.
- **Dependency injection** - same as for function parameters, just done a bit earlier (at object construction rather than function invocation). Be careful if your dependencies are mutable objects though, this can quickly cause the same problems as mutable global state.....
- **Immutable global state** is mostly harmless - it is effectively a constant. But make sure that it really is a constant, and that you aren't going to be tempted to turn it into mutable global state at a later point!
- **Immutable singletons** - pretty much the same as immutable global state, except that you can defer instantiation until they are needed. Useful for e.g. large fixed data structures that need expensive one-off pre-calculation. Mutable singletons are of course equivalent to mutable global state and are therefore evil :-)
- **Dynamic binding** - only available in some langauges like Common Lisp/Clojure, but this effectively lets you bind a value within a controlled scope (typically on a thread-local basis) which does not affect other threads. To some extent this is a "safe" way of getting the same effect as a global variable, since you know that only the current thread of execution will be affected. This is particularly useful in the case where you have multiple threads each handling independent transactions, for example.

Comment: I think that passing a context object either by function parameter or dependency injection would cause problems if the context is mutable, same problem as using mutable global state.

Comment: All good stuff, and amen! But the question is about immutable global state

Comment: @Alfredo - very true. Though it's not *as* bad since at least the scope can be somewhat controlled. But in general, it's easier to just solve the problem by making contexts and dependencies immutable.

Comment: +1 for mutable/immutable.  Immutable globals are ok.  Even ones that are lazy loaded but never change.  Of course, don't expose global variables, but a global interface or API.

Comment: @MarkJ: I cannot find the word immutable in the question, and there is no such thing as "immutable state": as soon as something is immutable, it is a constant and does not model any state. Maybe you meant global constants?

Comment: @mikera: Very good answer (+1), but are you sure that "immutable state" is a good formulation? State represents something that can change over time. In my understanding, something that is immutable is not state.

Comment: @giorgio The question makes it clear that the variables in question get their values at startup and never change afterwards during program execution (system folders, database credentials). I.e. immutable, it does not change once it has been given a value. Personally I also use the word "state" because it can be different from one execution to another, or on a different machine. There may be better words.

Comment: @Giorgio Once I started a [question here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/107769/14167) by "State: This is an immutable class...". This obviously means "a snapshot of the state" and the state variable changes by pointing to different instances. But isn't this obvious? When we say "the current state" we also mean a fixed thing, right?

Comment: @maaartinus: IMO you have just moved the mutation from the object (mutable object == object with mutable member variables) to the mutable variable that can point to different immutable snapshots (immutable objects). The state of your system is now represented by that variable. In a purely functional approach you would have a stream of immutable objects: both the objects and the stream are immutable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. And there's a variable declared as `State state` and that's why I call the class "State", too. A purely functional approach... I haven't really thought of it, sounds interesting.

Comment: @mikera could you give some read programming examples illustrating the `tricky bugs from mutable global state`? What I can think of is a simple one : consider a program for sending emails to users. Now users are getting stored in a static list.Now since static variables are loaded once when class is loaded and they persist throughout app life therefore for the first time say the program sent mail to u1 and u2. Next time if we want to send mails to u3 and u4 then being static list the mail will be sent to u1 and u2 again and this goes on.Pls let me know if my example is reasonable enough.

Comment: I find that mutable global state is OK if you put strict controls on it i.e. only one process is allowed to write to it and the rest can only read (assuming that you can guarantee this contract in a multi-developer environment)

Answer (score 69):

1. Since your whole damn app can be using it, it's always incredibly hard to factor them
   back out again. If you ever change anything to do with your global, all your code needs changing. This is a maintenance headache- far more than simply being able to `grep` for the type name to find out which functions use it.
2. They're bad because they introduce hidden dependencies, which break multithreading, which is increasingly vital to increasingly many applications.
3. The state of the global variable is always completely unreliable, because all of your code could be doing anything to it.
4. They're really hard to test.
5. They make calling the API hard. "You must remember to call SET_MAGIC_VARIABLE() before calling API" is just *begging* for someone forget to call it. It makes using the API error-prone, causing difficult-to-find bugs. By using it as a regular parameter, you force the caller to properly provide a value.

Just pass a reference into functions which need it. It's not that hard.

Comment: Well, you can have a global config class which encapsulates the locking, and IS designed to change state at whatever time possible. I would choose this approach over instantiating config readers from 1000x places in the code. But yes, unpredictability is the absolutely worst thing about them.

Comment: @Coder: Note that the sane alternative to a global is not "config readers from 1000x places in the code", but *one* config reader, which creates a config object, which methods can accept as a parameter (-> Dependency injection).

Comment: Nitpicking: Why is it easier to grep for a type than a global? And the question is about read-only globals, so point 2 and 3 aren't relevant

Comment: @MarkJ: You don't grep for a type, you use a static analysis tool/IDE to find it for you. As to "grep": Ever tried grepping for a global named "config"? Good luck! And the question does not say anything about the values being read-only (maybe the conf can be changed at runtime).

Comment: @MarkJ: I hope that nobody ever, say, shadowed the name.

Comment: @DeadMG, Re "..hidden dependencies..", they aren't hidden if you got an IDE and/or Ctrl-F.

Comment: @DeadMG, Re "..is always completely unreliable..", the same goes for dependency injection. Just because you made it a parameter doesn't mean that the obj is guaranteed to have a fixed state. Somewhere down the function you could have make a call to another function that modifies the state of the injected variable at the top.

Comment: @DeadMG, Re "..really hard to test..", Not true if you are smart about it. In fact, an IDE could tell you which variables in a class are global and which are not, effectively it's no different from dependency injection.

Comment: @DeadMG, Re "..If you ever change anything to do with your global, all your code needs changing..", Dude, it's the exact same thing with dependency injection. You have an obj that is injected in a hundred classes or is a parameter for a hundred functions, and you decide to change that obj, guess what happens?

Comment: @DeadMG, Re "..You must remember to call SET_MAGIC_VARIABLE..", don't be silly, there's no need for that. You call a global function and it takes care of all that.

Comment: @Pacerier: There's two key differences. The first is scale. If you inject a dependency into 100 classes, *you know you have 100 classes to change*. A global can affect *the entire application*- e..g 100,000 classes. The second is clarity- it's clear when you inject a parameter that you are adding that dependency, but when you access a global, there's no evidence on the caller's side that you have taken this dependency.

Comment: @Pacerier: The IDE and ctr+f will only work if you have all the source for every module that consumes the global, which is quite optimistic. Apart from anything else, first, you'd need to actually *know* who consumes the global. And I sure hope that there's no code that e.g. dynamically loads symbols or can produce references by macro expansion or any other of a thousand horrible ways to make this difficult to work with.

Comment: And frankly, you seem to be under the assumption that I think that injecting mutable state through DI is totally fine. It's not really fine. It's just not *as bad* as random global variables. You'r'e absolutely right that many of the same issues can occur if used unwisely.

Comment: So you can easily find out the locations where you inject state, but you couldn't find out if these exact locations would use the global? That's ridiculous. If anything, opposite is true, because accesses to global variables happen always by the same name. Which can't be said of injected state that is stored as local member variables.

Comment: I don't like the "you don't know what the state is" answer because you do know, if you study the code - just like everything else about the code. Points 1, 2, 4 and 5 are better.

Comment: @user253751 Studying the code doesn't tell you what the state is. It tells you what you think the state should be. Those are not the same thing. Additionally, studying the code in that kind of detail is incredibly painfully expensive because you would have to know your whole damn codebase to figure it out.

Comment: @DeadMG yeah, but taken to its extreme, you don't really know *anything* about the code, such as the fact it has global state in it

Comment: @user253751 There's no need to take to its extreme. A lack of knowledge about the code is relative. There might be bugs in my code I don't know about. I could have state that has unexpected values. But there's a difference between "I can't prove that's not true" and "I'm inviting it and maximizing the probability of it". Being unable to eliminate the situation completely doesn't mean you should just give up or let the worst come. If all you can do is minimize things you don't know about your program, then that's exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 36):

If you say "state", that is usually taken to mean "mutable state". And global mutable state is *totally* evil, because it means that *any part of the program can influence any other part* (by changing the global state).

Imagine debugging an unknown program: You find that function A behaves a certain way for certain input parameters, but sometimes it works differently for the same parameters. You find that it uses the global variable *x*.

You look for places that modify *x*, and find that there are five places that modify it. Now good luck finding out in what cases function A does what...

Comment: So *immutable* global state isn't so evil?

Comment: I would say that immutable global state is the well known good practice known as 'constants'.

Comment: Immutable global state is not evil, it's just bad :-). It's still problematic because of the coupling it introduces (makes changes, reuse and unit testing harder), but is creates much less problems, so in simple cases it is usually acceptable.

Comment: IFF one does use global variables then only one piece of code should modify it. The rest are free to read it. The issues of others changing it does not go away with encapsulation and access functions. Tis not what those constructs are for.

Comment: @sleske, As long as you are using `ClassFooBar` in multiple functions and you need to change its external definition, you're screwed.  It doesn't matter if the instance `foobar` is global or not global, even if its not global, you're still screwed. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil#comment774111_148110

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, changing a widely-used interface is difficult, no matter whether it is used as a global or local variable. However, that is independent of my point, which is that the _interaction_ of different pieces of code is difficult to understand with global vars.

Answer (score 11):

There are many problems with Singletons - here are the two biggest problems in my mind.

- It makes unit testing problematic. The global state can become contaminated from one test to the next
- It enforces the "One-and-only-one" hard rule, which, even though it couldn't possibly change, suddenly does. A whole bunch of utility code that used the globally accessible object then needs to be altered.

Having said that, most systems have some need for Big Global Objects. These are items which are large and expensive (eg Database Connection Managers), or hold pervasive state information (for example, locking information).

The alternative to a Singleton is to have these Big Global Objects created on startup, and passed as parameters to all of the classes or methods that need access to this object.

The problem here is that you end up with a big game of "pass-the-parcel". You have a graph of components and their dependencies, and some classes create other classes, and each have to hold a bunch of dependency components just because their spawned components (or the spawned components' components) need them.

You run into new maintenance problems. An example: Suddenly your "WidgetFactory", component deep in the graph needs a timer object that you want to mock out. However, "WidgetFactory" is created by "WidgetBuilder" which is part of "WidgetCreationManager", and you need to have three classes knowing about this timer object even though only one actually uses it. You find yourself wanting to give up and revert back to Singletons, and just make this timer object globally accessible.

Fortunately, this is exactly the problem that is solved by a Dependency Injection framework. You can simply tell the framework what classes it needs to create, and it uses reflection to figure out the dependency graph for you, and automatically constructs each object when they are needed.

So, in summary, Singletons are bad, and the alternative is to use a Dependency Injection framework.

I happen to use Castle Windsor, but you are spoilt for choice. See [this page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) from back in 2008 for a list of available frameworks.

Answer (score 10):

You sort of answered your own question. They're difficult to manage when 'abused,' but can be useful and [somewhat] predictable when used properly, by someone who knows how to contain them. Maintenance and changes to/on the globals is usually a nightmare, made worse as the size of the application increases.

Experienced programmers who can tell the difference between globals being the only option, and them being the easy fix, *can* have minimal problems using them. But the endless possible issues that can arise with their use necessitates the advice against using them.

edit: To clarify what I mean, globals are unpredictable by nature. As with anything unpredictable you can take steps to contain the unpredictability, but there's always limits to what can be done. Add to this the hassle of new developers joining the project having to deal with relatively unknown variables, the recommendations against using globals should be understandable.

Answer (score 10):

First of all for dependency injection to be "stateful", you would need to use singletons, so people saying this is somehow an alternative are mistaken. People use global context objects all the time... Even session state for example is in essence a global variable. Passing everything around whether by dependency injection or not isn't always the best solution. I work on a very large application currently that uses a lot of global context objects (singletons injected via an IoC container) and it has never been a problem to debug. Especially with an event driven architecture it can be preferred to use global context objects vs. passing around whatever changed. Depends who you ask.

Anything can be abused and it also depends on the type of application. Using static variables for instance in a web app is completely different than a desktop app. If you can avoid global variables, then do so, but sometimes they have their uses. At the very least make sure your global data is in a clear contextual object. As far as debugging, nothing a call stack and some breakpoints can't solve.

I want to emphasize that blindly using global variables is a bad idea. Functions should be reusable and shouldn't care where the data comes from -- referring to global variables couples the function with a specific data input. This is why it should be passed in and why dependency injection can be helpful, although you are still dealing with a centralized context store (via singletons).

Btw... Some people think dependency injection is bad, including the creator of Linq, but that isn't going to stop people from using it, including myself. Ultimately experience will be your best teacher. There are times to follow rules and times to break them.

Comment: Dependency injection does not need singletons.

Comment: @Basilevs Did you even read my comment. I never said it needed to be a singleton. I said if you want the object to be static/stateful, etc., a singleton is one way to get there.

Comment: first statement of your answer states so.

Answer (score 7):

Since some other answers here make the the distinction between *mutable* and *immutable* global state, I would like to opine that **even *immutable* global variables/settings are often an annoyance**.

Consider the question's:

> ... Let's say I need a global configuration for my application, for instance system folder paths, or application-wide database credentials. ...

Right, for a small program, this probably ain't a problem, but as soon as you do this with components in a *slightly* larger system, writing automated tests suddenly becomes harder because all tests (~ running within the same process) must work with the same global configuration value.

If all configuration data is passed explicitly, the components become much easier to test and you never need to worry how to bootstrap a global configuration value for multiple tests, maybe even in parallel.

Comment: No they don't. I used to think the same, but now that I inherited a massive project with _thousand_ of Global State switches that work together like _music_, everything covered to the minute detail by unit tests, my eyes have been opened. There are more ways to code, and incredibly elegant code can come from the use of any tool, including Global State. People just need to use it for the wrong things, like every other tool people misused before.

Answer (score 4):

The other problem curiously is that they make an application difficult to scale because thay are not "global" enough. The scope of a global variable is the process.

If you want to scale your application up by using multiple processes or by running on multiple servers you cannot. At least not until you factor out all the globals and replace them with some other mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one, you can run in to exactly the same issue that you can with singletons.  What today looks like a "global thing I only need one of" will suddenly turn in to something you need more of down the road.

For instance, today you create this global config system because you want one global configuration for the entire system.  A few years down the road, you port to another system and someone says "hey, you know, this might work better if there were one general global configuration and one platform specific configuration."  Suddenly you have all this work to make your global structures not global, so you can have multiple ones.

(This isn't some random example...this happened with our configuration system in the project I am currently in.)

Considering that the cost of making something non-global is usually trivial, it's silly to do so.  You're just creating future problems.

Comment: Your example is not what OP meant. You're clearly speaking of instantiating abstract configurations (just a configuration manager datastructure, without any application-specific preference keys) multiple times because you want to split all the keys in a running instance of your program across multiple instances of your configuration manager class. (Say, each such instance could handle one configuration file, for example).

Comment: A new feature in iOS is that one executable can appear in the user interface as multiple different applications. Suddenly you need one configuration per application which is multiple configurations per executable.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is Global State so Evil?

**Mutable** global state is evil because it's very hard for our brain to take into account more than a few parameters at a time and figure out how they combine both from a timing perspective and a value perspective to affect something.

Therefore, we are very bad at debugging or testing an object whose behavior has more than a few external reasons to be altered during the execution of a program. Let alone when we have to reason about dozens of these objects taken together.

Answer (score 3):

State is unavoidable in any real application. You can wrap it up any way you like, but a spreadsheet must contain data in cells. You can make cell objects with only functions as an interface, but that doesn't restrict how many places can call a method on the cell and change the data. You build whole object hierarchies to try to hide interfaces so other parts of the code *can't* change the data by default. That doesn't prevent a reference to the containing object from being passed around arbitrarily. Nor does any of that eliminate concurrency issues by itself. It does make it harder to proliferate access to data, but it doesn't actually eliminate the perceived problems with globals. If someone wants to modify a piece of state, they're going to do it weather it's global or through a complex API (the later will only discourage, not prevent).

The true reason not to use global storage is to avoid name collisions. If you load multiple modules which declare the same global name, you either have undefined behavior (very hard to debug because unit tests will pass) or a linker error (I'm thinking C - Does your linker warn or fail on this?).

If you want to reuse code, you've got to be able to grab a module from another place and not have it accidentally step on your global because they used one with the same name. Or if you're lucky and get an error, you don't want to have to change all the references in one section of code to prevent the collision.

Answer (score 2):

Globals aren't that bad.  As stated in several other answers, the real problem with them is that what is, today, your *global* folder path may, tomorrow, be one of several, or even hundreds.  If you're writing a quick, one-off program, use globals if it's easier.  Generally, though, allowing for multiples even when you only think you need one is the way to go.  It's not pleasant to have to restructure a large complex program that suddenly needs to talk to *two* databases.

*But they do not hurt reliability.  Any* data referenced from many places in your program can cause problems if it changes unexpectedly.  Enumerators choke when the collection they're enumerating is changed in mid-enumeration.  Event queue events can play tricks on each other.  Threads can always wreak havok.  Anything that is not a local variable or unchangable field is a problem.  Globals are this sort of problem, but you're not going to fix that by making them non-global.

If you are about to write to a file and the folder path changes, the change and the write need to be synchronized.  (As one of a thousand things that could go wrong, say you grab the path, then that directory gets deleted, then the folder path is changed to a good directory, then you try and write to the deleted directory.)  The problem exists whether the folder path is global or is one of a thousand the program is currently using.

There is a real problem with fields that can be accessed by different events on a queue, different levels of recursion, or different threads.  To make it simple (and simplistic):  local variables are good and fields are bad.  But former globals are still going to be fields, so this (however critically important) issue does *not* apply to the Good or Evil status of Global fields.

**Addition:** Multithreading Problems:

(Note that you can have similar problems with an event queue or recursive calls, but multithreading is by far the worst.)  Consider the following code:

```
if (filePath != null)  text = filePath.getName();
```

If `filePath` is a local variable or some kind of constant, your program is *not* going to fail when running because `filePath` is null.  The check always works.  No other thread can change its value.  *Otherwise*, there are no guarantees.  When I started writing multithreaded programs in Java, I got NullPointerExceptions on lines like this all the time.  *Any* other thread can change the value at any time, and they often do.  As several other answers point out, this creates serious problems for testing.  The above statement can work a billion times, getting it through extensive and comprehensive testing, then blow up once in production.  The users won't be able to reproduce the problem, and it won't happen again until they've convinced themselves they were seeing things and forgotten it.

Globals definitely have this problem, and if you can eliminate them completely or replace them with constants or local variables, that's a very good thing.  If you have stateless code running on a web server, you probably can.  Typically, all your multithreading problems can be taken on by the database.

But if your program has to remember things from one user action to the next, you will have fields accessable by any running threads.  Switching a global to such a non-global field will not help reliability.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this?: _"Anything that is not a local variable or unchangable field is a problem. Globals are this sort of problem, but you're not going to fix that by making them non-global."_

Comment: @AndresF.:  I extended my answer.  I think I'm taking a desktop approach where most people on this page are more server-code-with-a-database.  "Global" may mean different things in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

When it's easy to see and access all of the global state, programmers invariably end up doing so.  What you get is unspoken and difficult to track dependencies (int blahblah means that array foo is valid in whatever).  Essentially it makes it nearly impossible to maintain program invariants since everything can be twiddled independently.  someInt has a relationship between otherInt, that's hard to manage and harder to prove if you can directly change either at any time.

That said, it can be done (way back when it was the only way in some systems), but those skills are lost.  They revolve mostly around coding and naming conventions- the field has moved on for good reason.  Your compiler and linker do a better job of checking invariants in protected/private data of classes/modules than relying on humans to follow a master plan and read source.

Comment: "but those skills are lost"... not entirely yet. I recently worked at a software house that swears by "Clarion", a code generator tool that has it's own basic-like language that lacks features such as passing arguments to sub-routines... The sitting developers were not happy with any suggestions about "change" or "modernizing", finally got fed up with my remarks and portrayed me as deficient and incompetent. I had to leave...

Answer (score 2):

Languages that are designed for secure & robust systems design often get rid of global *mutable* state altogether.  (Arguably this means no globals, since immutable objects are in a sense not really stateful since they never have a state transition.)

[Joe-E](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/joe-e-ndss10.pdf) is one example, and David Wagner explains the decision thus:

> Analysis of who has access to an object and the principle
>   of least privilege are both subverted when capabilities are
>   stored in global variables and thus are potentially readable
>   by any part of the program. Once an object is globally available, it is no longer possible to limit the scope of analysis:
>   access to the object is a privilege that cannot be withheld
>   from any code in the program. Joe-E avoids these problems
>   by verifying that the global scope contains no capabilities,
>   only immutable data.

So one way to think about it is

1. Programming is a distributed reasoning problem.  Programmers on large projects need to divide up the program into pieces which can be reasoned about by individuals.
2. The smaller the scope, the easier it is to reason about.  This is true both of individuals and static analysis tools that try to prove properties of a system, and of tests that need to test properties of a system.
3. Significant sources of authority that are globally available make properties of the system hard to reason about.

Therefore, globally mutable state makes it harder to

1. design robust systems,
2. harder to prove properties of a system, and
3. harder to be sure that your tests are testing in a scope similar to your production environment.

Global mutable state is similar to [DLL hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).  Over time, different pieces of a large system will require subtly different behavior from shared pieces of mutable state.  Solving DLL hell and shared mutable state inconsistencies requires large-scale coordination between disparate teams.  These problems would not occur had the global state been properly scoped to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not gonna tell if global variables are either good or bad, but what I'm going to add to the discussion is to tell the fact that if you are not using global state, then you are probably wasting a lot of memory, especially when you use classess to store their dependencies in fields.

For global state, there is no such issue, everything is global.

For example: imagine a following scenario: You have a 10x10 grid which is made of classess "Board" and "Tile".

If you want to do it the OOP way you will probably pass the "Board" object to each "Tile". 
Let's say now that "Tile" has 2 "byte" type fields storing it's coordinate. The total memory it would take on 32bit machine for one tile would be (1 + 1 + 4 = 6)bytes: 1 for x coord, 1 for y coord and 4 for a pointer to the board. This gives a total of 600 bytes for 10x10 tiles setup

Now for the case where the Board is in global scope, a single object  accessible from each tile you only would have to get 2 bytes of memory per each tile, that's the x and y coordinate bytes. This would give only 200 bytes.

So in this case you get 1/3 of the memory usage if you only use global state.

This ,besides other things , I guess is a reason why the global scope still remains in (relatively)low level languages like C++

Comment: That's *highly* dependant on the language. In languages where programs run persistently, it may be true that you're able to save memory by using global space and singletons instead of instantiating many classes, but even that argument is shaky. It's all about priorities. In languages like PHP (which is run once per request, and objects don't persist), even that argument is moot.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No, this argument is not shaky in any way. That are objective facts, unless some VM or other compiled language does some hardcore code optimisation with this kind of issue. Otherwise it's still relevant. Even with server side programms which use to be "one shot" the memory is reserved through the time of execution. With a high load servers this may be a critical point.

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors to consider with global state:

1. Programmer memory space
2. Immutable globals/write once globals.
3. Mutable globals
4. Dependency on globals.

The more globals you have, the greater the chance of introducing duplicates, and thus breaking things when duplicates get out of sync. Keeping all of the globals in your fallible human memory becomes both necessary and a pain. If it’s a mutable global, then there’s a greater chance that function A makes a change, with incorrect the expectation that the value will be changed when function B is subsequently called.

Immutables/write once are generally OK, but watch out for initialization sequence errors.

Mutable globals are often mistaken for immutable globals…

A function that uses globals effectively has extra "hidden" parameters, making refactoring it harder.

Global state isn't evil, but it does come at a definite cost – use it when the benefit outweighs the cost.

Answer (score 1):

What makes global state bad is not that it is global, but that basically every single line of code could change the global variable, or could be affected if it is changed.

The minimal change in C or C++ would be to make the variable static. Which means access, changes, and being affected by a change would be restricted to a file. But then I could write a global accessor function to read and write that static variable and we are right where we started: Any line of code could change the variable or be affected by a change.

If you are lucky you have an editor that cooperates with the compiler and lets you search for a symbol: You select say a global variable, tell the editor “search for symbols” and it shows you all the places where this global variable is used. And not a local variable or a member or a function with the same letters.

What also hurts is not just the fact that a global *could* be used anywhere but actually *is* used in many places. That’s something you should avoid first.