# Why singleton is an anti-pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns, singleton

Many articles in Internet say that singleton is an anti-pattern, because it makes debugging more difficult.

However I don't understand **why** debugging a program with a singleton object is difficult. Please explain.

I think that singletons are inevitable, when we need (usually for performance reasons) lazy initialization of a controller object. Or are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

Singletons are not always inevitable, you can use the [monostate](http://wiki.c2.com/?MonostatePattern) pattern in a lot of cases, however, it has the same issues as singletons, most notably it is to do with governing global state.

For why having global state is bad, take a look at the following stackoverflow post: [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Personally, I prefer to have a monostate class over a singleton as it allows me to inject this as a dependency rather than referencing the singleton's concrete implementation (via `MyClass.Current`), at least with a monostate you can abstract away the fact that there is a single instance of data, and allows me to test classes relying on it easier.

Comment: "A monostate is a "conceptual singleton" - all data members of a monostate are static" from http://wiki.c2.com/?MonostatePattern that sounds rather nasty as well. Why not use simple IOC where you have full control?

Comment: I didn't want to assume that the OP was using an IOC container.  As you suggest, you may register your instance as a singleton if you wish, but in the end you are still left with global state.

Comment: We don't need to use a container to use IOC. It is just a pattern.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen, "We don't need to use a container to use IOC". Without a container, it's not IoC; it's just DI. But that's a common problem with IoC/DIP/DI, it's a great way to write code, but everyone seems to have a slightly different idea as to what the terms mean.