Why is global state hard to test? Doesn't setting the global state at the beginning of each test solve the problem?
According to Why is Global State so Evil?, I know one of the disadvantages of "global state" is that it makes code "harder to test". I do not disagree with this, but what I don't understand is, why would it be "harder to test"?
I know there are some answers talking about "harder to test", for example:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109 : Unable to run tests with starting state, so the next test may start from altered global state and hence the value to assert is unknown

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148188 : After running a test, the global state changes, the next test would run using the altered state instead of initial state


But the premise of those answer is: after I test a method with a global state, the state is changed and the next test must use the altered state instead of the original state. My question is, why do the answers assume that? If I need to test a function with a global state, doesn't "setting the global state at the beginning of each test" already solve the problem? eg:
public void testCalculateTotalPrice(){
    UserData.instance=new UserData(); //reset the global state
    //assert(this.calculateTotalPrice(10 //price of the product,3 //quantity),1200); // calculate would use UserData.isMember : member have discount
}

And I know there are other answers about global state which say we cannnot easily switch an implementation:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148154 : unable to switch to test database from other database
However, I think the "unable to switch" problem is not caused by global state: I may create a switchable global state, eg:
public class UserData{
    IDatabase instance;
}

public interface IDatabase{
}

public testMethod(){
    UserData.instance=new TestDatabase();
    this.method(); //method that would use UserData.instance
}

So "global state" doesn't mean "unable to switch".
While "global state" may have tons of disadvantages, "harder to test" seems not to be among it, because I can still test a method depending global state with its initial state by reverting the global state to the initial state at each time testing. Also I can setup a replaceable global state to switch implementation. Why would we say "global state" is "harder to test"? Do I have a misunderstanding about testing methods with global states? Or do I have some misunderstanding about testing?
Note: I guess there would some people argue that when I use global state, besides the initial state, I need to test other possible states, eg:
public class UserData{
    public boolean isMember;
    public boolean isVIP;
    public static UserData instance;
}

public void testCalculatePrice(){
    UserData.instance.isMember=false;
    UserData.instance.isVIP=false;
    assert(this.calculatePrice(10,3),1200);
}

So you may complain that this test only tests
UserData.instance.isMember=false;
UserData.instance.isVIP=false;

but not other cases such as
UserData.instance.isMember=true;
UserData.instance.isVIP=false;

But if you eliminate the global state with "parameter version":
public void testCalculatePrice(){
    assert(this.calculatePrice(10,3,false,false),1200);
}

I guess you would not complain why I don't have:
assert(this.calculatePrice(10,3,false,true),1200);
assert(this.calculatePrice(10,3,true,true),1000);
assert(this.calculatePrice(11,3,true,true),1100);

right? And even if you complain, I believe the source of problem is not because it is using global state, but you missed some other important test cases: the problem of "need to test all possible combinations of global states" is equivalent to "need to test all possible combinations of values of parameters".
Yes, resetting global state would ensure the method works with specific global state only, not other global state , but "parameter version" also ensure the methods work with specific parameter values only, why would we challenge the ability of covering test case in "global state" versions, but not in "parameter" version?
So the question is, why does using global state require us to test all possible states, but not in "parameter version"?

It seems you skipped the explanation in the last answer you linked to: Poor testability - if you have mutable global state, you will need to configure it for any tests that you write. This makes testing harder (and people being people are therefore less likely to do it!). - What's unclear with that explanation?

Nobody uses global state that responsibly and cleanly in real life. That's probably where the disconnect is for you with this particular pearl of wisdom. This is a heuristic that will statistically help you write better more testable code, not a description of a deterministic law of the universe where every use of global state cannot ever be tested.

I guess the main issue of this question is the implicit assumption that programs are evenly small like these tiny little examples where it is easy to identify global variables or other forms of global state for each "subject under test". wcminipgasker, you are asking lot of questions over the last weeks where I am under impression you are studying Software Engineering from a purely theoretical point of view, but never came in contact with a real-world program. Is that true? (No offense, I am just asking to understand our audience.)

Isn't the fact that there is a solution to the problem proof enough that there is a problem in the first place? In the end you have two options: solve the problem or work around it.

Ease of testability depends upon isolation for being able to control your invariants.   By definition, global state lacks isolation;  which means there is no limit to what some future developer may unknowingly do to change or break the invariants that your code relies upon.   You can only write code and tests with the invariants that you have at the time; it's not possible to write code or tests for invariants that don't exist.   There's just no way to write tests that protect themselves from unknowable future changes to global state which might invalidate your code or tests.

It's not that you can't simulate a global state and write tests that appear to cover the code.  It's that those tests don't cover the actual working conditions -- where other subsystems may be altering the global state.  So the tests don't do a good job of reproducing bugs or telling you where you have problems.

How do you know where all the global state is in your application?
When you have a function which does not use global state, all the information required for test state is in the parameters. When a function does use global state, there is no easy way (at least not in any language I've seen) to get a list of relevant global state so you can reset it. And in a large codebase which doesn't have a "no global state" rule, the amount of global state may become very large.
Sometimes the global state simply isn't resettable from the outside either, because it's private.

And even if there were a way "to get a list of relevant global state so you can reset it": What happens if, in the future, your implementation decides to access another piece of global state? Without global state, you need an additional parameter to your method, your unit test won't compile any more, and you'll be forced to modify it. With global state, your unit test will run fine as before and you might never notice that you fail to cover an important test case.

I was going to say the same thing... the biggest problem with global state is that it makes it hard to keep track of which bits of state are relevant.

If you reset the global state before each test, each test will execute in a known global state and will, therefore, be consistent.  Trouble is, that's not how it will be executed in the real application.
Now, you could make the argument that this is "OK" for Unit Testing.
When invoked in a known (single) state, the code works.  All the real application stuff falls under "Integration" Testing, and that's the Testers' job, right?
I would disagree.
Instead, you could consider the code a "fixed point" and that you need Unit Tests that "cope" with how that global state changes.  That way, you could be confident that each, individual invocation would work and your "Integration" Testing piece would just be "bolting together" these individual cases.  Everybody wins.
The "trick", though, is that you don't know how or when that global state is going to change.  Being manipulated by code outside of your control it could, potentially, even change during the execution of any given test!  Talk about building on shifting sands.

"That could be an awful lot of combinations" is correct, but "you need a Test for every, single one." not (you will not even be able to test every single possible input data combination for a pure function with a huge range of possible parameters, that's technically infeasible). The point is, for writing good tests, you need a test for every single interesting input data combination - where interesting means "something which has a certain chance of revealing a bug", ideally a different bug than other input data. And that is what gets hard with too much global state.

... hence I recommend to edit your answer, with some minimal changes I think it can be heavily improved.

A problem that I've encountered as well is with tests running in parallel. One test sets the global state to something and runs checks. Meanwhile a different test starts running and changes the global state. Test 1 now fails because the state is different from what was expected. We could force the tests to run sequentially instead of parallel, but with a lot of tests that could add quite a bit to the time it takes to run them

@DocBrown: As I understand, "Something which has a certain chance of revealing a bug" is not the only tests that are interesting - you would also want "This test of non-interesting, normal values, that should not reveal a bug should work, regardless of the failure rate of the 'interesting' cases.", and "This will cause the code to fail, presuming there is not a bug.".

@AlexanderThe1st: you missed my point. This answer says literally "exhaustive test cases are necessary" and "exhaustive tests can be created for functions which avoid global state, but not for functions which depend on global state". But this is, to be straight - nonsense. It is totally impossible to create exhaustive tests even for a pure function which takes just one double value as input, because that whould mean 2^64 test cases. And I have no idea why Phil refuses to correct this nonsense. it could turn a mediocre answer into a good one by a simple, small correction.

@Doc Brown: No question of refusing to change it, just haven't got around to it yet.  Inconvenient things like the Day Job getting in the way of the "Fun" stuff.  ;-)

@PhillW.: +1 for a heavily improved answer, and sorry, I think my former comment could have been more polite.


My question is, why would the answers assume that?

Because it is the default unless you change it.

If I need to test a function with a global state, isn't just "restoring the global state at the beginning of each test" already solve the problem?

Yes... if you never run tests in parallel.
And if you are one of the people who say "why would I run them in parallel", I can tell you that you have never actually written tests for a larger application. Because you can easily cut the time your tests take by 95% if you write them to run in parallel on todays processors.
You would not accept single-threaded applications from any other vendor, why write your own software that way?

While a multitude of tests that can share the same immutable global state may be able to run more efficiently than if the state had to be duplicated for each test, running each test in an independent process with its own global state wouldn't seem difficult, and could sometimes improve performance if tests that used shared state would need to use memory barriers when accessing it.

"running each test in an independent process with its own global state" will absolutely wreck you on Windows if you need to spawn a new process for each test, because the process startup time is fairly high.

@supercat immutable global state isn't the problem. But immutable isn't the default in many languages

@pjc50: That will be true if processes have to exit and relaunch, but if one has one process per core which can set global state, run a test, set global state, run a test, etc. I don't see why that should cause a performance problem unless there's a lot of global state that would be shareable if it weren't necessary to run everything in a separate process (in which cases increasing the cache footprint could be a downside).  What else am I missing?

@supercat: I had the same thought myself, but though it is possible, it may be impractical due to the extra complexity of managing inter-process work-stealing queues of tests, added on top of the difficulty in finding a resetting all global state (while not affecting the state of the test runner itself).

@BenVoigt: If there are two designs, one of which uses a global state for some things which in the other would need to be passed to all functions that use it, it should be pretty clear what aspects of global state would need to be dealt with in the first that wouldn't also need to be dealt with in the second.  If there are many places where global state is used to avoid passing a parameter, tracking them all may be more of a nuisance than passing around all of the required parameters, but passing around that many parameters isn't apt to be much fun either.

@supercat: The problem with referring to the second design (that passes parameters) in order to write tests for the first design (that directly accesses state) is that that second design wasn't developed, it's only a hypothetical.  The design which passes parameters which are groups (compounds, structures, aggregates -- different names in different languages) can be less work than either of the two extremes.  Passing access to a few unneeded-but-related variables is quite practical and less harmful than exposing access to the whole world.

In an application, you usually start with global state initialised from settings and preferences, and then you add more state as the application is running.
When you call a method in real code, it assumes that the global state is there. Some is required for the method to work, some influences what it does. (You may say that’s a bad idea, but if we assume you have global state then I assume you use it)
If you just reset global state, you have two problems: One, your method may not be working. Two, you only test how the method works with one specific global state. So to test the method properly, you’d have to set up each legal global state and call the method repeatedly with each state. So it’s a bit of a mess.

Yes - effectively, the global state acts as a large number of extra parameters to the code under test.  Even assuming it's possible to access the state (e.g. it's not in a static local in a C function).

@Toby Speight Lets add to that... A lot of hidden extra parameters whose use (read only, write etc...) is not documented. And can only be found by a thorough examination of source code... Is liable to be missed/overlooked. And whose state will not be a part of a stack trace.

aren't all these arguments valid against config, whether implemented with global state or not?

One thing i don't see anyone else bringing up here is the set of unique bugs that global state makes more likely. Especially raceconditions become a lot more likely to occur in an application with global mutable state. Raceconditions are notoriously difficult all around, and writing a automatic test suite that reliably protects against them is somewhere between almost impossible and actually impossible. Now, testing to ensure you don't have raceconditions is difficult in an application that doesn't have global state too, but you are much less likely to run into them, and therefore don't have the same need to test for them.
Basically, global states puts you in a place where you need to test for raceconditions, and that's hard

I think the last sentence of this answer is what the OP is missing, and something that other answers might be alluding to, but are not outright saying. Global state = bugs due to race conditions because multiple processes or threads can write to data while you are trying to use it. This is nigh impossible to write a proper unit test covering these kinds of bugs. Do the OP a favor and prefix the markdown of your last sentence with ## so it stands out more.

And remember, @wcminipgasker2023, "hard" does not mean writing the test is hard. Code can be hard to test, because the test does not actually verify how the code will behave at runtime. When your code is subject to race conditions because you use global state, the test does not verify runtime behavior (no matter how "easy" it is to write the test). Passing tests are not enough.

@GregBurghardt ## is markup for headers, I would say it's abusing this semantic markup for „bigger text“ that's not actually a header.

I think you're conflating two things, basically the words "any" and "all".
Does there exist global state that can be tested in the way you describe?
Yes. In a suitable language you could define a class TestableGlobal, which holds a value with getter and setter, plus a "reset" operation. Also, on creation, instances register themselves in some kind of collection. Then, the test just has to call some static function clear_all_testable_globals, which iterates over every instance of TestableGlobal, and resets them all.
Then, the code under test can safely use global data, provided it is all managed using TestableGlobal.
If we press this TestableGlobal concept a bit further, we can probably get to 85% of the functionality of a dependency injection framework with 15% of the work. Or, we could do what the thread you're reading already suggests, and use a dependency injection framework.
Can all global state be tested in the way you describe?
No, because in the massive variety of programming languages that we might be talking about, and features of those programming languages that the code under test might use, there are plenty of forms of global state that the test code cannot easily access in order to reset them, or which can only access given extremely detailed knowledge of the implementation of the code under test, which makes the tests very far from black box testing.
In the example you give, suppose that the code under test starts using a second global. Then, the test doesn't work any more, but the code hasn't changed its public interface in any way. This is a very bad state of affairs: we much prefer to write tests that don't rely on the test code "knowing" the non-public implementation details of the code under test. So, by using globals, the code is unarguably "harder to test". We have to do work to fix the tests when we change the code. Things that required more work are by definition "harder" than things that require less work!
For another example, suppose the system has an attached radio telescope, and the code under test moves the telescope from its "rest position" pointing due upwards, to point at the Andromeda galaxy. Then the test code needs to know how to rest the "global state" of the radio telescope: that is to say the test code needs to call a function to move the radio telescope back to point due upwards. At some point in this process, perhaps when your test run is keeping you awake due to the noise from the telescope motors, will you not think to yourself: "using an injected dependency for the radio telescope, instead of global state, so that most of my tests can be run using mocks, would be easier than this"? And that's just when Andromeda is above the horizon.

And then how shall one test the "testable globals" to ensure that they indeed reset state completely?

@BenVoigt: Carefully, with one process per test :-)

Trusting a global is like eating off the floor.

why would it be "harder to test"?

Because a global is known, globally.

doesn't "setting the global state at the beginning of each test" already solve the problem?

Sure. Right up until it doesn't. Wash the floor all you want. Soon as you run some code lord knows who has walked all over your "clean" floor.
Whatever else a global is, it isn't yours. You have no reassurance over the life it leads. Even if you trace everything that refers to it today who knows what knows about it tomorrow.
You have to depend on things to get things done. We've proven over and over that when you do that it's best to make what you depend on yours. Get your own copy of it that nothing else knows about. Now you know where that floor tile has been.


Why is global state hard to test?

Global state is a subtle way of coupling every function that uses it. Setting the state before each test case is all fine and well, but guess what's not happening in the running production code: the global state is typically not being neatly reset before every function call.
The order of operations of a running program can be hard to understand as it is, but on top of that, some of the functions to be called may be determined at runtime, by user actions. As a result, you'll run into bugs that are due to global state being altered by one function in a way that some other function didn't expect, messing up your code in ways you didn't even think of. The problem with global state is that, when  you're implementing any particular function, too many things can go wrong with other (ostensibly unrelated) functions because of reasons you initially aren't aware of, and soon you have this web of complexity that will make working in this codebase a miserable experience. It's going to turn into the "if you touch anything at all, something might break" type of codebase. The problem is that if you're not very careful, global state soon severely limits your ability to reason about the correctness of a function based on only the code in the function itself.
These bugs may be hard to replicate, and my only happen intermittently, after the user performs some very specific, obscure sequence of operations. These bugs are hard to test in a broader sense of the word: they are hard to reproduce, hard to debug and figure out, hard to fix or mitigate cleanly without accidentally breaking something else, and can also be hard to simulate/capture in unit tests.

Doesn't setting the global state at the beginning of each test solve the problem?

While setting global state at the beginning of each test case will let you test your functions under ideal conditions, the above means that there's a whole class of bugs that you're not covering at all, and that you might not even be able to cover effectively because of how convoluted the circumstances that give rise to such bugs can be. Simply having some tests running is not the point - the point is to have a suite of tests that gives you confidence that (1) your code does what it is meant to do, and (2) still works correctly after changes are made to a part of the system.

I believe the source of problem is not because it is using global state, but you missed some other important test cases: the problem of "need to test all possible combinations of global states" is equivalent to "need to test all possible combinations of values of parameters".

From a high level point of view, yes, global state can be seen as input to your function, but the devil is in the details. It's not necessarily about a particular global state being invalid as input, it's that there will be a bunch of unexpected flows of logic spanning several functions, resulting in sequences of states changing over time, that will lead to unexpected or unpredictable results.
A certain global state might be a perfectly valid input for a given function, and the function might correctly compute what it was supposed to compute with such input. Still, the unexpected thing might be that you arrived at that state in the first place, because that wasn't supposed to happen in a given scenario. E.g., maybe your user can't click on a menu item, because it's disabled, when in fact it shouldn't be. There's nothing wrong with the function that is in charge of the menu. There's something wrong somewhere else in the logic flow, and it may be a result of an "unrelated" bugfix you did three weeks ago. You'll be banging your head trying to figure out what sequence of events lead to such an outcome, and the bug will be in some bizarre place, not in the menu code, and not in the bugfix code.
With a function (or an object) that avoids globals and has well-defined inputs and outputs, and well-defined behaviors, you can reason about its correctness locally (without worrying about other code), and you can write a more effective, more structured set of tests. Furthermore, going one level higher, when reasoning about the correctness of the code that calls such functions, you don't have to go back one level down to look inside those functions in order to understand what is going on.1 Now apply this idea recursively all the way up. If done well, many of the aberrant flows of logic that can arise with global state will not be possible by design. If there is a bug, you're way more likely to find it in a place that makes sense, and fix it without affecting anything else.

1 To some people, this may sound like a pipe dream, but consider that you do it all the time when calling library functions. Imagine that simply calling a library or a framework function had a potential to break your own code somewhere else, and that then you had to look at the freakin source of the library to figure out why. Generally, you don't know or care how those library functions are implemented, you know what they do in the high level sense, and that's enough for you to understand the workings of your own function that utilities them. Well defined inputs, well defined outputs, predictable behavior. And the library itself is encapsulated and has no direct access to your own state, it only interacts with your code in a very structured way. Well, write your own code with a similar philosophy, in a smaller scale. As a rule of thumb, strive towards being able to treat calling your own code as calling a library function that's safe and predictable.

"A certain global state might be a perfectly valid input for a given function, and the function might correctly compute what it was supposed to compute with such input. Still, the unexpected thing might be that you arrived at that state in the first place, because that wasn't supposed to happen in a given scenario." - why is this specific to global variables? Why couldn't an explicit input to a function suffer the same problem, where the input is sometimes valid so the function handles it, it's just that input shouldn't have occurred on that occasion?

@Steve - I'm not saying this is specific to global state, I'm pointing out to the OP that this is also a possibility, in response to their idea that the problem will be solved by just "writing all the important test cases". But, I am saying that, with global state, there are potentially many more ways in which such situations can arise, and that it will often be harder to track down the problem, or fix it without impacting something else.

Actually it wouldn't be that hard to find (with a Find All) the places where a global variable is assigned, nor (by substituting direct field access with global static calls) would it be massively difficult to intercept/log the assignments. Certainly a lot easier than tracing through different call arguments, and stages, and layers, and compilation units even. The disordered access that can make the use of global variables difficult to fault-find, can also make all other methods difficult to fault-find.

@Steve - I'm not talking about simply finding stuff. I'm talking about actually figuring out what's going on, and about even having to do so in the first place. I'm not saying it's impossibly difficult, just that it's generally a massive but avoidable waste of time, compared to working with better designed code (assuming you know what you're doing design-wise). That said, there are no absolutes claimed here; simply not using globals doesn't automatically make good design, and global state can also be accessed/modified in a very structured, very disciplined way - but typically isn't.

"assuming you know what you're doing design-wise ... simply not using globals doesn't automatically make good design" - that's the key I think. The use of global variables or not doesn't alter the competence of the designer. Yesteryear, the incompetent programmer would have made a mess with global variables, whereas the competent programmer used them without trouble. Nowadays, we hear that using global variables is a signal of incompetence - so everyone avoids showing the signal, but the incompetent quickly finds new ways to make the same mess he would have made with the global variables.

I don't think there is one universal understanding of what "global state" even is.
I suppose it is commonly used as a synonym for "global variables" - that is, a facility offered by certain programming languages where fields exist in a "global scope", are allocated automatically at the start of runtime, and are accessible from anywhere in the program.
By definition, these global variables cannot be reallocated at run time, access cannot be intercepted or diverted at all, and access can originate from anywhere in the program without further ado and without any possible constraint.
This doesn't make global state untestable, but the inability to easily intercept or divert the access makes it more difficult to apply certain testing methods which depend on presenting certain carefully-set testing data, or on immediately checking the correctness of what is submitted.
The unrestricted access also creates widespread and direct dependency on certain global fields,
This facilitates (though it does not inherently cause or require) the disorderly design of data flows that make it difficult to divide the program into parts and test them severally - the assumption being that it is easier to test parts than to test the whole.
The direct dependency on global fields (even if they are pointers that can be intercepted/diverted) also means these fields must be reproduced in a test environment - this can make it more difficult to set up a test environment as the linkage has to occur at compile time.
The alternative to unrestricted global access is to have some feature of the code that explicitly distributes access to certain fields.
Access can still ultimately be distributed globally (so it doesn't automatically solve disordered design which is difficult to test in separate parts), but the important difference for testing purposes is that, when under test, something other than the normal thing can be distributed around instead - something like a specially prepared mock - and the linkage to this thing can be established at runtime rather than compile-time - so for example, a precompiled library can be put straight into a new test environment, without recompiling the library source code together with the test environment incorporated.
It's important to remember that the difference is only about how difficult certain testing methods and styles end up being. The use of global variables alone is not the difference between some piece of code being completely and easily testable, and being completely untestable by any means.

“Global variables” is just an implementation detail how “global state” can be implemented.

@gnasher729, indeed, but the "global variables" kind presents some particular difficulties to testing which are not general to all forms of "global state". The kinds of problems which are general to all forms of global state, are more attributable to "non-local state with disordered access patterns" - a much more complicated condition to illustrate or to fix, because all useful programs require some kind of non-local state, there is no specific criteria to define orderly access for all circumstances, and what amount of order is required depends on the overall complexity of the program.

Global state is state that is not accessed through parameters (directly or chained).

@jmoreno, the problem with parameters is that you can easily pass in pointers and dereference them, and in that way distribute access paths widely (or even globally). The problems which global variables suffer from, can mostly return this way. You also have to remember that the "state" relevant to testing for many applications can consist of more than just one program at runtime - it includes the contents of the documents they manipulate, or the central databases they access (which will often be under concurrent access from multiple clients). As I say, there isn't a universal understanding.

"... and are accessible from anywhere in the program." Often not true - for example, a memoised function uses a cache to store its results. The cache is global state, but can only be accessed by the function itself.

@kaya3 Wiktionary defines global as "2. (not comparable) Pertaining to the whole of something; total, universal:
2.1. (not comparable, computing) Of a variable, accessible by all parts of a program". Wikipedia says "In computer programming, a global variable is a variable with global scope, meaning that it is visible (hence accessible) throughout the program, unless shadowed. The set of all global variables is known as the global environment or global state." A cache isn't global state, even if it shares some of the testing problems of global state.

The definition you cite from Wiktionary is for "global variable", not for "global state"; and anyway I would not recommend relying on a general-purpose dictionary for the precise technical meaning of a term. Wikipedia is generally good on computing topics, but the article you quote is the one titled "Global variable", and its claim about global state is unsourced (and the article has a banner at the top saying the article lacks citations for its claims).

Google's style guide for Python, for example, defines "mutable global state" as "Module-level values or class attributes that can get mutated during program execution", which includes any values (not just variables), and they don't have to be public. Your definition doesn't account for the way the term "global state" is commonly used e.g. in questions like this one which talk about private global state (by your definition, this would be an oxymoron).

Here's another example which defines global state as "state whose lifecycle is long and shared across different contexts", not limited to public global variables, and this blog post argues that PHP's global variables aren't global state because they don't persist across different HTTP requests.

@kaya3 To quote that example in full, "We often read about local state and global state to refer to state whose lifecycle is short and bound to a specific context, and state whose lifecycle is long and shared across different contexts." A cache is not shared across different contexts. I checked the "Komputada leksikono" which translates global as "malloka", defining that as (translated) "declared at the outermost declaration level", if you want a technical dictionary.

@kaya3 Wikipedia does not have an article on "global state", which brings into question whether it's really a generally understood term that means something besides "global" + "state". I don't think that global state is limited to global variables, but it's surely exclusionary of local state, like caches accessible to just one function.

@kaya3, would it be a "global variable" if it wasn't "accessible anywhere"? The part you quote from me was specifically on global variables, not all kinds of "global state", and I specifically talked about the problem of varying understandings of the latter term.

@Steve The part I quoted is from your first paragraph which claims that global variables are conventionally synonymous with global state. I argued that they are not synonymous because, for example, global state need not be accessible from everywhere in a program (at least, not directly accessible). Your answer doesn't propose any other meaning for the term "global state" as far as I can tell.

@prosfilaes Local state is state which does not persist between invocations of the same function. A cache for a memoised function persists for the lifetime of the program. It may not be accessible directly from outside the function, but it can be accessed indirectly from anywhere, via calling the function. Even so, whether or not the cache is publicly accessible is an implementation detail; for example, a cache in a "private" class attribute in Python is still publicly accessible through its mangled name, but nobody is supposed to access it, and this doesn't change any design considerations.

@kaya3, 1. I'm going to change the wording from "it is synonymous with" to "it is used as a synonym for" - so as to better imply that "global state" is often used to mean "global variables", without implying that "global variables" is used in the other direction as a synonym for "global state". 2. The reason I propose no other definition is because, as I say, the term is already used in a very muddled way to refer to so many different things. I can sense the entanglement of meaning when others talk, but I'm not myself in a position to articulate a clear picture overall. (1/2)


As for global state not being globally accessible, I prefer the term "non-local state", because we're often talking about data that affects the program over relatively long distances and the difficulty of reasoning and design this entails, not necessarily talking about data whose accessibility is inappropriately wide or totally uncontrolled (as with global variables). Maximising locality and moderating non-local workings down to the essential and irreducible cases, so as to minimise the difficulty for the programmer in grasping the workings, is part of the art of good design. (2/2)


@kaya3 local state is alternately "state whose lifecycle is short and bound to a specific context"; it simply doesn't have one universal definition. A cache for a memoised function is an implementation detail; an outsider observer can't prove whether or not the function has a cache, or whether that cache is implemented in user code or elsewhere.

@kaya3 Brushing off the public accessibility as an implementation detail seems to be missing some of the point. Many languages (Java, C, C++) make exposing private state possible. If programmers in the larger system use mangled names, or reflection, or unions or whatever to access what nobody is supposed to access, then it becomes global state, or more global state I guess under your definitions, and moves from something that can be tested locally to something that can only be tested as a whole program.

There are already good answers, but one additional consideration for some cases:
Global state management (reset and access) likely will require global initialization, i.e. to first reset the global state you might have to initialize your full application - which could be a massive multi-component server that takes a minute to boot up (exaggerating...perhaps...) just to reset the global state. If you want to test a small piece of code that could run isolated when it wouldn't rely on global state, no need to first setup the whole application.
